# Odd characters in LXTerminal with RealVNC viewer

Tags: linux, vnc, lxterminal

Image below shows the output from `service cron status`,  via **ssh** on the left, **LXTerminal** via **RealVNC** on the right.

[image: screenshots]

Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

```
# File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU.UTF-8
```

*Edit:*  I'm starting RealVNC from ssh with: `vncserver :0 -randr=1910x1005`

Comment: have you fiddled with the locale/localisation settings of the pi?

Comment: I did `raspi-config` -> Change Locale -> `en_AU.UTF-8` as part of the initial install.

Comment: You've rebooted since? what is the contents of `/etc/default/locale` - I found that can sometimes be left broken after `raspi-config` (when I say broken, I mean things like this happen :p)

Comment: Yes, have rebooted since.  (See original question for file contents, not sure how to format nicely in comments..)

Comment: Mine has a single line (well, two including the comment) ... `LANG=en_AU.UTF-8` (yes, I'm a fellow Aussie) try editing yours to match that, and restarting (keep a copy of the original though)

Comment: don't worry, I could read it (put it in the **question**)

Comment: If that doesn't help, try removing one or other of the last two lines - again, rebooting ...

Comment: Removing line(s) in various combinations and rebooting didn't help :(  Not sure if it's relevant, but the `locale` command shows empty fields for those 3 lines, and "POSIX" for all the rest.  *(oi oi oi)*

Comment: Your LXTerminal is not configured to handle UTF-8 sequences.

Comment: Ok... any idea how to configure it?